# How can I make a short tutorial adventure for Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, adventure-writing, system-introduction

How do I design a short "Tutorial mode" adventure for pathfinder? I want to GM one for 2 of my players, to help them get into the normal mechanics of pathfinder, and show them how it works. It should be short, i.e. 1 session or less.

What it should do:

- Teach the player combat mechanics of Pathfinder
- teach how skills work without having them have to use every skill in the game
- not have it be very long. I want this to be a tutorial before we go on to real campaigns.

Is there a sensible way of doing this?

My problem is how to do so without making it seem like a tutorial.

Comment: Asking "How do I design an adventure of the kind I have in mind" is much too broad a question. What specific part of designing your adventure are you struggling with?

Comment: Well. I wanted a campaign that teaches the standard concepts the players would need to understand to play pathfinder. Something I could pull out and teach the players through play in a short time.

Comment: That's just repeating the question, which doesn't tell us anything new. I asked what specifically you're struggling with to try to narrow this down to something that won't be closed. What roadblock are you running into when you try to design what you're imagining? What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The issue is likely that Cataru _does not have_ the expertise required to make such an adventure. I wouldn't either! What is and is not important to put forward requires a knowing author. If it's pretty simple to put one forward, an answer can probably describe that. And Cataru _has_ described what kind of adventure they have in mind: a tutorial thing! Details irrelevant, answers can say what is and is not important to have. You are probably grilling someone for detail they cannot provide, and the question should be taken at face value.

Comment: @doppelgreener I would think this is simply too broad then: better on a forum, or requires some time in research and self-directed learning first to ask it more narrowly.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie [A question just like this for 4e](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/9422/1204) did pretty well. I do not believe this is too big for us to handle. Cataru only wants to demonstrate a limited section of the game.

Comment: @doppelgreener If this was similarly asking about one tutorial encounter I'd agree, but not while it's asking for an entire campaign.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's asking for a short campaign, set in 1 session or less. It is probably not even right to call it a campaign.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22778/discussion-between-doppelgreener-and-sevensideddie).

Comment: Actually, I'm going to rename this to ask for an adventure, not a campaign - 1 session or less is not a campaign, just an adventure.

Comment: Either way, that circles back to my first comment: how to design an adventure is too broad; answers that are narrow will be fairly opinion-based if they go beyond "just have a combat, and some skill-check situations."

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Again, look at the 4e question that went fine. "Just put them through a basic adventure. Bear these things in mind when you run it." Whatever works solves the problem, and this is easily solvable and fits our system under GSBS coming from some expert advice on what's worked. It does not take much. How to design an adventure is certainly too broad, _but this one has specific goals that have been stated._

Comment: Voting to close as there is no clear problem statement. You want to write a tutorial. You think it feels too much like a tutorial. Ok. Post what you've got, post the problems you see, *then* we can help you with a clear cut problem.

Comment: @doppelgreener I don't think this should be closed either, but I would like to know what, in the author's opinion, makes an adventure *seem* like a tutorial.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I mean by it seeming like a tutorial as in "you are tossed into an arena where the main guy throws 4 goblins at you. And with this happening, this is how combat works." Kinda thing.